# Borrar la fila seleccionada desde un dialogo de Material Design Lite

Tags: javascript, revisión-de-código, material-design-lite

Tengo esta tabla de ejemplo hecha con [material design lite](http://www.getmdl.io/index.html). La última columna de la tabla tiene un botón **BORRAR** que al ser presionado debe mostrar un cuadro de diálogo donde se da la opción de borrar la fila seleccionada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora mismo éste es mi código. Al parecer está funcionando, sin embargo, estoy usando una variable global `fila` que no me gusta demasiado. ¿Qué recomendaciones me pueden dar para mejorar este código?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <dialog class="mdl-dialog">
      <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Borrado filas</h4>
      <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
        <p>
          Desea eliminar la fila seleccionada?
        <p>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
        <button type="button" class="mdl-button aceptar">Aceptar</button>
        <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">Cancelar</button>
      </div>
    </dialog>

    <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Material</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
          <th>Borrar</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Acrylic (Transparent)</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td><button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button borrar">Borrar</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Plywood (Birch)</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td><button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button borrar">Borrar</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td><button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button borrar">Borrar</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
      var showDialogButton = document.querySelector('#show-dialog');
      var fila; //variable global
      if (! dialog.showModal) {
        dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
      }
      $('body').on('click', '.borrar', function(e) {
        fila = $(this).parent().parent();
        dialog.showModal();
      });
      dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
        dialog.close();
      });
      dialog.querySelector('.aceptar').addEventListener('click', function() {
        fila.remove();
        dialog.close();
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres evitar la variable global, una opción sería añadir una clase (o un atributo `data-*`) a la fila con la que estás operando. Entonces: si el usuario pulsa en "Cancelar", se quita la clase de la fila; o si el usuario pulsa en "Aceptar" se elimina el elemento que tenga esa clase.

Aunque no directamente relacionado con la variable global, otra cosa que cambiaría en el código es esto: `$(this).parent().parent()`. Eso funciona bien con la estructura actual, pero si cambias la estructura en el futuro, tendrás que cambiar esa línea también. En cambio si lo reemplazas con `$(this).closest("tr")`, ya no te tienes que preocupar de si el botón cambia su posición relativa dentro de la fila.

Así el código quedaría de este modo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <dialog class="mdl-dialog">
      <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Borrado filas</h4>
      <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
        <p>
          Desea eliminar la fila seleccionada?
        <p>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
        <button type="button" class="mdl-button aceptar">Aceptar</button>
        <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">Cancelar</button>
      </div>
    </dialog>

    <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Material</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
          <th>Borrar</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Acrylic (Transparent)</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td><button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button borrar">Borrar</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Plywood (Birch)</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td><button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button borrar">Borrar</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td><button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button borrar">Borrar</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
      var showDialogButton = document.querySelector('#show-dialog');
      if (! dialog.showModal) {
        dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
      }
      $('body').on('click', '.borrar', function(e) {
        $(this).closest("tr").addClass("active-row");
        dialog.showModal();
      });
      dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
        $("tr.active-row").removeClass("active-row");
        dialog.close();
      });
      dialog.querySelector('.aceptar').addEventListener('click', function() {
        $("tr.active-row").remove();
        dialog.close();
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me gusta esta solución, evito usar la variable fila.

Comment: Una solución limpia, que evita variables JavaScript innecesarias y aprovecha las características de HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

La primera solución para eliminar el uso de las variables globales es usar un [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), de esa forma todas las variables que declares son locales y no hay contaminación del `global scope`.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
  var showDialogButton = document.querySelector('#show-dialog');
  var fila; //ya no es global sino una variable local limitada al ámbito del IIFE
  if (!dialog.showModal) {
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
  }
  $('body').on('click', '.borrar', function(e) {
    fila = $(this).parent().parent();
    dialog.showModal();
  });
  dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
    dialog.close();
  });
  dialog.querySelector('.aceptar').addEventListener('click', function() {
    fila.remove();
    dialog.close();
  });

}());
```

El `IIFE` te lo puedes encontrar en estos dos formatos. Lo único que cambia es la posición de los paréntesis invocadores.

```
// Pasa jslint y jshint
(function() {

} ());

// No pasa jslint pero si jshint
(function() {

})();
```

La opción que te recomiendo y segunda variante es que envuelvas todo tu código en una función [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) de jQuery ya que **los IIFEs no son un remplazo para estos eventos**. Estos de ejecutarán de manera inmediata y en tu código hay un script con atributo `defer` lo que significa que será ejecutado despues que el documento sea cargado lo que puede dejar tu función `dialogPolyfill` como undefined por ejemplo.

```
$(function() {
   'use strict';

   var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
   var showDialogButton = document.querySelector('#show-dialog');
   var fila; //ya no es global sino una variable local limitada al ámbito del la función anónima que le pasas a jQuery

   if (!dialog.showModal) {
       dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
   }
   $('body').on('click', '.borrar', function(e) {
       fila = $(this).parent().parent();
       dialog.showModal();
   });
   dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
       dialog.close();
   });
   dialog.querySelector('.aceptar').addEventListener('click', function() {
       fila.remove();
       dialog.close();
   });
 });
```

Cualquiera de estos dos formatos es recomendado

```
$( document ).ready( handler )
$( handler )
```

Por último y como nota personal veo que en algunos lugares usas jQuery y en otras javascript puro para los selectores. Te recomiendo consistencia, si decides poner jQuery usa jQuery porque los navegadores tienen inconsistencias entre sí y jQuery se encarga de lidiar con estas en tu lugar, de otra forma te tocaría a ti lidiar con ellas para tener una experiencia uniforme. Este es un consejo a modo general, no necesariamente aplica a tu fragmento de código.

Comment: Si, tienes razón trataré de ser mas consistente. Gracias por la sugerencias.